# Removing leading and trailing double quotes in string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to trim the leading and trailing quotes of a string without any replacement.. I have tried with gsub.. but nothing helped.. I want to achieve something like., "hai" to hai

In Java, I ll use like the following.,

```
String a="\"hai";
String z=a.replace("\"", "");
System.out.println(z);
```

Output:

hai

How can I achieve this in rails? Kindly pls help..

In my irb

```
2.2.3 :008 > str = "\"hai"
  => "\"hai"
2.2.3 :009 > str.tr!('\"', '')
  => "hai"
```

Why am I not able to get output without double quotes?? Sorry ., If my question doesn't meet your standard..

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `.tr` method.

```
str = "\"hai"
str = str.tr('\"', '')

##OR

str.tr!('\"', '')

## OUTPUT
"hai"
```

Comment: Thank you .. but again am getting the double quotes around the word.. please look at my question.. I have edited it.. Is that default ?

Comment: The values of String always have single or double quotes, that's why you are getting quotes around the word.

Comment: If the word doesn't have single or double quote around ruby will consider as variable.

Comment: Thank you @Amit. I guessed that.. But was trying to remove for some operations to get performed. But str.tr method works fine.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regex instead, try this

```
str = "\"hai"
str = str.gsub(/\"/, '')
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This removes the leading and trailing double quotes from the string only. You get a new string and keep the old one.

```
str = "\"ha\"i\""
# => "\"ha\"i\""
new_str = str.gsub(/^"+|"+$/, '')
# => "ha\"i"

str
# => "\"ha\"i\""
```

Or you change the original string.

```
str.gsub!(/^"+|"+$/, '')
# => "ha\"i"
str
# => "ha\"i"
```

That's a ruby convention. Method names with an exclamation mark/point modify the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str = "\"hai"
str.tr('"', '')
```

Note that you only escape (`\"`) double-quotes in a string that is defined using double-quotes (`"\""`), otherwise, you don't (`'"'`).